# Wave maps, second energy inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, semi-riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

Sorry in advance for the long setup:

Let $u: V \rightarrow M$, where $(V,g)$ is a Lorentzian manifold and $(M,h)$ is a Riemannian manifold. Also $V=S \times R$, where $S$ is an $n$-dimensional orientable smooth manifold, $R$ is 1-dimensional. $M$ is $d$-dimensional. $G$ is a Robertson-Walker metric $g=-dt^2+R^2(t)\sigma$.
Now i $\partial_i u^A$ and $\partial_t u^A$ are mappings from $S \times R$ into $T^∗ V\otimes TM$.

$u$ is supposed to be a wave map, so $g.\nabla^2 u=0$.

I also have the formula

$(\nabla_{\alpha} \nabla_{\beta}- \nabla_{\beta} \nabla_{\alpha})\partial_{\lambda} u^A =R^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta \lambda}\partial_{\mu} u^A + \partial_{\alpha} u^C \partial_{\beta} u^B R^A_{CBD} \partial_{\mu}u^D$

Here, latin indices $\in \{0,...,n\}$, small letters $i,j,.. \in \{1,..,n\}$ and capital letter indices $A,B,... \in \{1,...,d\}$.  $R$ are the Riemann curvature tensors resp. for $V,M$.

Also, $D_i$, respectively $ D_t$ are defined as covariant derivative in the metrics $\sigma$ and pull back of $h$ of a mapping from $S$ into $T^∗ S\otimes TM$;the
covariant derivative in the pull back of $h$ of a mapping from $R$ into $TM$. With this definition, the wave equation is the same as

$-R^{-n} D_t(R^n \partial_t u)+R^{-2} \sigma^{ij} D_i D_ju=0$

**Now I read the following**:

The expression of $\nabla^{\lambda} \nabla_{\lambda} u^A$, the definitions of $D$ and $D_t$ with the use of the Ricci formula
for the commutation of covariant derivatives lead to the equations where latin indices are
raised with $\sigma$:

$D_i \nabla^{\lambda} \nabla_{\lambda} u^A =-D_tD_i \partial_t u^A -n R^{-1} R^{'} D_i \partial_t u^A+ R^{-2} D^hD_h \partial_i  u^A - f^A_i=0$

where

$f^A_i=  R^A_{B C D} \partial_i u^B \partial_t u^C \partial_t u^D+R^{-2}( - \theta^j_i \partial_j u^A+ R^A_{ BCD} \partial_i u^B \partial^h u^C \partial_h u^D=0)$

where $\theta_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor of $\sigma$.

I don't understand this at all. It would already help me a lot if someone could answer me the questions:

- What does "where latin indices are
  raised with $\sigma$" mean?
- What does the expression $D^hD_h$ mean?
- Why are the expressions $=0$?

Comment: 'where latin indices are raised with $\sigma$' -- this refers to the second factor of the Robertson Walker metric. Index raising is done with the metric tensor (e.g. $v^i = g^{ij} v_j$), and in this special case they say you have to use $\sigma^{ij}$ for raising latin indices....if I got you right I helped you a lot/3 ;-)

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate anyone who bothers to read the whole long question, so thanks! Still, I don't understand it yet..There are only latin indices on the left side of the equation, right?

Comment: if you look at the indices in, say, the first equation which you've written down after 'Now I read the following' you will note that there are both greek and latin indices in use. So what the author (?) wants to tell you is that in case of latin indices the meaning of, say, $u^A$, is $\sigma^{AR}u_R$ instead of $ g^{AR} u_R$ (in the second case it would even be a different index range, since $g$ lives in a space which included the $t$ component). This statement is necessary since the whole construction involves different metric tensors.

Comment: (and no, there are also $\lambda$s, but regardless of that, you need to know which metric was used to raise or lower the indices).

Comment: Oh well, I mixed up latin and greek indices... still, in your explanation, $A$ runs from $1,...,d$ but $\sigma^{ij}$ from $0,..,n$.

Comment: $\sigma^{ij}$ runs from $1,..,n$, not $0$, but still $d \neq n$ ist possible.